# Feynman Parameters vs Passarino-Veltman reduction

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, integration, quantum-chromodynamics

I have computed the following one-loop integral:

$$\int \frac{d^dp}{(2\pi)^d} \frac{p^{\mu}p^{\nu}}{(p+k)^2p^2}.$$

Using both Feynman Parameters and the Passarino-Veltman reduction. However, while I have found the same divergent parts, the finite parts are not the same. According to the book "QCD: Renormalization for the practitioner", the result that I have got using Feynman Parameters is the right one.

Did I make a mistake using the Passarino-Veltman reduction or is it that it gives a different finite part? This really puzzles me because the Passarino-Veltman reduction is really easy to do in this case and I do not see any mistakes. Besides, both methods give the same result for

$$\int \frac{d^dp}{(2\pi)^d} \frac{p^{\mu}}{(p+k)^2p^2}.$$